# Make the default behavior of split window resize consistent

Tags: split

I use the keybinding <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>>/<</kbd> to increase/decrease width of the split window, and that works just fine when the split window is in the left.

However when I switch to any split beside the one on the far left, I don't feel like this specific movement is natural because now the key binding <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> starts to increase the current split window and vice versa .

Is there any way to make <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>>/<</kbd> consistent, *i.e.*, always increase / decrease the width of the current split irrespective of its position?

A more accurate query is a way that makes <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>>/<</kbd> move the split window's vertical line right (>) or left (<) with relation to decrease / increase in width of the current split ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note about consistency: current behavior is consistent, increase or decrease window size. For the leftmost/rightmost windows though it is impossible to decrease/increase to the left/right due to natural constraints (terminal window/gui window) thus it does it eating space of other splits.

So back to your request, what you can do is to analyze output of `winlayout` function and decide what to do with the split depending on current window position.

It wouldn't be that simple, so here is the simplified example that would "work" only for a simple layout (all windows are vertically split):

```
func! Resize(dir, count) abort
    if winnr('$') == 1 | return | endif
    let dir = a:dir
    if winnr() == winnr('$')
        let dir = !dir
    endif
    let cmd_dir = dir ? '+' : '-'
    exe "vert resize ". cmd_dir . a:count
endfunc
nnoremap <C-w>> :<C-u>call Resize(1, v:count1)<CR>
nnoremap <C-w>< :<C-u>call Resize(0, v:count1)<CR>
```

Comment: I included it right now and it worked just fine , but turned out that actual behavior i needed was the vertical line movement with relation to the size . i edited the question and hopefully its unambiguous this time

Comment: it wouldn't be that simple. First you should define behavior of the mappings for various split windows in many different layouts (for example: vert, hor, vert, vert, hor, vert, hor, hor...) and only after that you could script it analyzing where current window is splitted in, using output of `winlayout` func...

Comment: yes ,that seems quite convoluted . however the current binding is the closest one to the desired behavior

Comment: @polendina for a simple layout, check updated version. You can try to enhance it with better analysis where your current window is and what to do then.

Comment: how is the first proposal different from the default behavior?

Comment: @Mass it is the same, indeed.

Comment: @Mass the proposal itself was ambiguous and couldn't describe the actual needs to achieve the behavior , i intuitively felt that i need to move the left number line/left border of each split with the > to move the left border right / and < for the left border of the split to move left

Comment: @MaximKim for a layout with just vertical splits , the function works if there are two splits . however if there are a third one in the middle ,then the left border of the third split is the one that moves

Comment: @polendina Then you should probably clearly define everything in your question, given the layout if I am in this split and press this map, I want this. And that is for all edge cases. Hopefully then somebody would be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following layout.  If you are in window 2, what should `ctrl-w >` do?  It's ambiguous regardless of whether you think `>` should widen the window, or move the split bar.

vim takes the following definitions: 1) `>` always increases the width of a window- makes it greater (>).  2) The right split is always moved unless it's impossible, in which case the left split is moved.

```
----------------
|    |    |    |
|  1 |  2 |  3 |
|    |    |    |
----------------
```

It seems that (besides the apparent reversion of `<` and `>`) the *most* confusing case is around the latter portion of (2), where `>` moves the left split to the left.

We can use the following map to handle this special case (based on Maxim Kim's suggestion).

```
func! Resize(dir, count) abort
    let l:dir = a:dir
    if winnr('l') == winnr()
        let l:dir = !l:dir
    endif
    execute 'vert resize' (l:dir ? '+' : '-') . a:count
endfunc
nnoremap <c-w>> :<c-u>call Resize(1, v:count1)<cr>
nnoremap <c-w>< :<c-u>call Resize(0, v:count1)<cr>
```